# How to determine the server type in PHP with obfuscated "SERVER_SOFTWARE"

Tags: php, apache, nginx, lighttpd, mod-security2

I've secured my server using "mod_security2" and changed the "Server:" header to a different value.  It says: "Server: exampleserver".
I used the following mod_security options:

```
ServerTokens Full
SecServerSignature exampleserver
```

A side effect is that `$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]` also equals "exampleserver".

Therefore **the typical code to determine the server type no longer works**:

```
if( strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Apache') !== false) 
  echo 'Have Apache';
else
  echo 'Have some other server';
```

While checking the information available from PHP, I found that this particular PHP7 setup has the "apache2handler" extension loaded in Apache.

So I updated my test to:

```
$isApache=  extension_loaded('apache2handler')
          ||(strpos(getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE'),'Apache')!==false);
```

**Is there a better way to determine what the type of server is inside PHP when `$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` is not available ?**

Comment: If it runs as mod_php, you'd have the [according functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php) available.

Comment: @mario On lighttpd, apache_get_version does not exist, on apache it returns the same value as $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] -  <?php
if(function_exists(apache_get_version)) {
  echo apache_get_version();
  echo '<br />';
}
echo php_sapi_name();
echo '<br />';
echo phpinfo();

Comment: Ummm. If you control what the answer to the server signature is, why not plug the value you used there into the PHP test?

Comment: One purpose to change the signature is to obfuscate information about the version.  So all servers have the same signature - without the version.  The server type also changes.
I was also looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`php_sapi_name()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) to determine how PHP is running. On my web server, this returns "apache2handler." On the command line, it returns "cli."

Comment: Where apache2handler is used, it reports apache2handler, but on a lighttpd server I have running, php_sapi_name() reports 'cgi-fcgi'.  So this potentially reports the same when its connected to apache2 thorugh
FastCGI rather than the Apache2.0 handler.